# Finding all files based on partial filename match and display file size

Tags: terminal, find

I am using SSH to access my Ubuntu system and I have 100s of files across 100s of folders which are called `xxxxx.mail.log` or `xxxx.mail.log.xxx`
I need to list all these files, and see their file size.

I have already tried `ncdu`, which works, but I can’t search for filenames with it. Doing it manually with `ncdu` takes hours.

What’s the easiest way to search my system for all files that contain `mail.log` in their filename, and have them listed and display the file size?

Comment: `find / -name "*.mail.log*" -printf "%s\t%p\n"`

Comment: What does the `-printf "%s\t%p\n"` do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
find / -name "*mail.log*" -printf "%s\t%p\n"
```

`-printf` prints some information about each match, in this case:

```
%s - size of file in bytes
\t - tab for spacing
%p - pathname
\n - newline
```

See [man find](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) and search for "printf format" to list all possibilities for the printf statement.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. What I used in the end was `find / -name "*.mail.log*" -printf "%s\t%p\n" >findresults.txt` then downloaded the file and copied the content into google spreadsheet and ordered by the file size column.

Comment: @KevinM, the sorting could easily be done in the same command pipeline (although redirecting to a file and manipulating that works also).   `find / -name "*mail.log*" -printf "%s\t%p\n" | sort -n`

Comment: @ user4556274 Ah, thank you. I'll keep that in mind for next time.